# Как правильно объеденить пользовоталей двух сайтов на yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Может у кого-то была, такая задача? Пока что пытаюсь сделать это в лоб, просто объединяя две таблицы `user`  в одну на первом сайте. Наверняка возникнет куча ошибок с теме же `id`шниками`, там куча внешних ключей, и т.д.

Может есть какой-то более простой способ в yii2?

Comment: Что значит обьединить? Совместить данные из одной таблицы с другой? И зачем, для чего, какой конечный смысл?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это описано в вопросе, чтобы на одном сайте совместить пользователей с двух